# Possibly unsurprising riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I'm really confused
I sound like subtraction
But really I've refused
A positive action

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> **nonplussed**.

I'm really confused

> Nonplussed is a synonym for confused.

I sound like subtraction
But really I've refused
A positive action

> These refer to the mathematical meaning of "plus." "Non-plus" can mean the opposite of addition i.e. subtraction, or the refusal of addition (a positive action).

Title: Possibly unsurprising riddle

> Interestingly, nonplussed can also mean unperturbed, meaning the word can be its own antonym!

Comment: Well done, and nice explanation!